# How do I instruct entity framework to choose migrations based on the current database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

So when a developer starts up our application locally, it will be against a blank, localhost database. But in production we will first need to migrate all of the old ASP.NET Membership Framework tables and data to the new ASP.NET Identity framework tables.

How can I write EF6 migrations to consider this? Also, our existing production database has no __Migration table in it.

Comment: See http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity Migrating an Existing Website from SQL Membership to ASP.NET Identity

Comment: @RickAnd-MSFT - Thanks for the link. I've already put in the code to migrate from Membership to Identity, but for a developer that has a blank database, how would I handle this scenario?

Comment: if you have a blank DB, then you can let Migrations create the tables for you.

Comment: @RickAnd-MSFT - Yah, this is the point of confusion for me. How do I code my migration to create tables, or migrate an existing database?

Answer (score 0):

**When moving from Identity to Membership with data to be ported from old tables**: You can create the tables that are according to Identity schema using SQL scripts. Else if you change your app to use Identity, running and creating user a first time will create the tables for you via code first. You can then copy the data from the old tables through a console application or via SQL scripts.

If you want to run migrations to create a new Identity tables before you run your application, you can do it by running the following steps
- Enable-Migrations
- Add-Migration 
- Update-Database

This will create the empty tables for your according to your DbContext. If it extends from IdentityDbContext, it will create the tables according to Identity schema along with the _MigrationHistory table. Hope this helps